# Can we transfer users data from a Consumer app type to Gaming Services app type in Facebook in Unity?

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I have a game on Facebook and it is integrated in Unity and it has an app type of **Consumer.**
I also have some users which are already logged into the game using Facebook, and they have some in-game data. Let's say that a Facebook user has an id of "XYZ".

Now, I have created another game with the same name but I have selected the app type to be **Gaming Services**, as I wanted the new features of Facebook Login for Gaming, to be added into my game.

When I log into the **NEW** app, with the **same user**, I get a different id, i.e., "ABC".

Since, the user id is different, we get to know that these two are different users. So, we create 2 different users with different in-game data.
But, the main goal was to preserve the in-game data of the old game users and take all the data with them in the new game.

If the user id was same as the old game, we could instead get all the in-game data, rather than creating a new user.

So, we need to transfer the data of the old game users into the new game users.

One solution was instead of checking of the user ids, we could check for the email address, that can be obtained by asking for the email permission while logging in. But, the issue in this was that some users couldn't send the email address with the access token, or some users would decline the email permission while logging into the game.

The expected result was we should always get the email address to check for any existing email address and get the in-game data.

Comment: You can not always get an email address, simple because a part of the user base might not even have one on file with Facebook - if they registered using their mobile.

Comment: Yes, since that is the issue, the only way we could solve this if we could get the same user id as in the old game, rather than getting a different user id in the new game.

Comment: User IDs are app-scoped, have been since API v2. If your apps belong to the same business, then you can match user IDs across apps - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching#given-a-user-id-for-an-app--retrieve-the-ids-for-other-apps-owned-by-the-same-business

Comment: I will have to verify my business for both the apps so that I can use the ids_for_apps endpoint.